# Manually widen type

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

Is there any way to specify that I want a type that is the widened version of another type?

My use case is something like this:

```
function times<A extends number, B extends number>(a: A, b: B): A & B;
```

The idea is that this `times` function will retain any extensions on `A` and `B`, but the value itself will be changed to `a * b`.

The problem is, if I call `times(2, 3)` I get a return type of `2 & 3`, which is both incorrect and impossible. I have no need for it to be `6`, but I definitely don’t want it to be `2 & 3`, I want it to be `number` in that case.

Type widening usually occurs “automagically” in Typescript, with various arcane rules. Usually, it just causes me headaches, but for once I find myself wanting it, but it doesn’t happen here. In a lot of similar circumstances, I certainly wouldn’t want it to, but this is definitely where where I want it to.

So what I want is some way to indicate a return type of `WidenedVersionOf<A> & WidenedVersionOf<B>`. Is there any way to do such a thing?

---

Some rationale/response to the anticipated “why don’t you just use composition?”

Yes, the extensions to number types are important here. I am well aware that a wrapping object with the value stored as a number and the extension stored separately would be the “better” way to do this in most cases. This is not most cases. What we are actually doing is using [branded primitives](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) for units of measure (e.g. seconds, feet). That means these extensions only actually exist in the type domain, and are not present in the runtime. That has a number of advantages for us.

We do have a finite number of brandings (the primary ones are `In`, `Per`, and `Delta`, so we could have `const v = 20 as number & In<'feet'> & Per<'second'>` or `const d = 100 as number & In<'feet'> & Delta`). The `times` function has a large number of overloads to cover all of those cases. However, we also have a lot of generic containers that store numbers of any kind of branding, using `N extends number`. It is specifically this case that causes problems with the overload of `times` described above. It is not plausible (nor, I think, possible) to have every one of those generic containers separately handle all of the various cases of `In`, `Per`, and/or `Delta` that might appear.

Comment: Oh, you're using [branded primitives](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal).  So you want to widen `6 & In<T>` to `number & In<T>` and not to just `number`.  Hmm...

Comment: Can you maybe edit this to be a [mcve]?   I think this is an intriguing question but I don't want to spend time giving you a solution that doesn't meet your use case.  Like, I sincerely doubt you actually want `number & In<'Newtons'> & In<'meters'>` since that will become equivalent to `number & In<never>` the way you have `In` defined.  I'd love to see some code that works exactly how you want it at the type level *except* that `times()` isn't working because of the literals.  Right now it's not quite there.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the terminology, didn’t realize there was a name for them. We’re not actually handling multiple units in the numerator or denominator—those versions of `times` return `never`—because we have no call for it from our project. So `times(threeMeters, fourNewtons)` just returns `never`. We do, however, also have a `Per` defined analogously to `In` that we use for the denominator. There are also other “brandings” that we use, such as `Delta` (though that doesn’t come up much for `times`, but `minus` returns it), and also generics that are just `N extends number` that need support.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my best answer to this, assuming that you are using `In<T>` as described in your question, and forgetting about the fact the intersection `In<A> & In<B>` will not really represent the same type is `In<A*B>`.  Instead you'll need some other way to take `A` and `B` and produce the type corresponding to `A*B` that keeps track of powers of units and cancelling, etc.  Intersection is unlikely to do this.  That aside, here:

```
class In<T> { private __v!: T };

function withUnit<N extends number, T extends string>(n: N, t: T): N & In<T> {
  return n as any;
}
const oneNewton = withUnit(1, "Newtons"); // 1 & In<"Newtons">
const oneMeter = withUnit(1, "meter"); // 1 & In<meter>
```

That's kind of like what you're doing, right?

Anyway, the `Widen` below specifically will only work on types of the form `number & In<T>`.  As far as I know there's no way to iterate over intersections, so one cannot programmatically take an arbitrary type `5 & Foo & Bar & Baz` and get `Bar` out of it without already knowing about `Bar`:

```
type Widen<N extends number> = N extends In<infer T> ? number & In<T> : number;
```

And here's `times` as asked:

```
declare function times<A extends number, B extends number>(a: A, b: B): Widen<A> & Widen<B>;
```

Which works as you wanted for these:

```
const six = times(2, 3); // number
const twoMeters = times(2, oneMeter); // number & In<"meter">
const alsoTwoMeters = times(oneMeter, 2); // number & In<"meter">;
```

But does bizarre things here due to the above caveats:

```
const oneSquareMeterUhWait = times(oneMeter, oneMeter); // number & In<"meter">;    
const twoNewtonMetersUhWait = times(2, times(oneNewton, oneMeter)); 
// number & In<"Newtons" & "meter">
```

With the basic scheme in `Widen` you can extract the units from a numeric type and then combine them *somehow* at the type level, but that's beyond the scope of the question.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#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-ElnzEZH0fLSGGrTGjQGE-OCaAA)

Comment: Ah, my apologies; I was too brief in my description of the rationale, and led you astray a bit: `number & In</*...*/>` is *not* the only cases we have. In particular, `N extends number` comes up, where we don’t know anything about it but we want to maintain `N` so long as it’s not a numeric literal. Question updated, and my apologies. Yes, for many cases `times` looks quite a bit like this, but for the cases where we don’t know about `In` and/or `Per` and just have `N`, we have a problem. Sounds like an unsolvable one.

Comment: Hence the request for a [mcve].   As I said above, you have to know *something* about it because you can't iterate or distribute over intersections the way you can with unions.  You likely have *some* finite list of cases you cover, so you can manually extract those like `number & (N extends In<infer T> ? In<T> : unknown) & (N extends Per<Infer T> ? Per<T> : unknown) & ....`.

Comment: Aren't you in control of how primitives get branded?  Is it really the case that you get some `N extends number` and have absolutely no idea about what possible types have been intersected with it?  If so, yeah, you're stuck.  I suspect otherwise, though.

Comment: So, more-or-less, yes, there are a finite number of cases for `times` to handle—and it does, much as you do here—but having every generic container of numbers, like `interface Point<N extends number> { x: N, y: N }` or `interface Box<N extends number> { x: N; y: N; w: N & Delta; h: N & Delta; }` (`Delta` is `As<'delta'>` where `As` is again defined much like `In`) *also* be forced to handle all of those iterations is problematic. We could have a generic that handles numbers in pixels or in feet or in hertz (`Per<'seconds'>`), or in dimensionless numbers.

Comment: As for a minimal reproducible example, while `times` has many overloads before the one in the question, the one in the question *is* an overload, and specifically is the overload that is causing problems, specifically in the cases where we are multiplying a `N extends number` with a literal. Luckily, we only have a handful of cases of this sort right now, so casting `as number` is workable here if there is no better answer.

Comment: I'm only saying that `Widen<T extends number>` would need to know about all the things you are planning to intersect `number` with, since you can't extract arbitrary things from intersections.  The signature for `times()` would still be able to be `Widen<A> & Widen<B>` if that meets your needs.  I don't mean to imply that the signatures of functions or types that accept these types would have to individually care about them.